# How to split a US mobile number before storing it into database?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to store a US mobile number in a database. Yet, before I would store it, I need to split the number into 3 parts. The Zip Code, Area Code and then the number.
Eg: +1 (213)-435-4676. I need to split this number, Zip code (213), Area Code (435) and then number (4676).

Is there any simpler way to do this in the controller point, after passing the argument? Or can I do it in the View using jQuery or javascript? What is the best possible way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: string.split('-')

Comment: you can do it in either context. In both situations you just split the string. Of course you could require the user to enter it just as digits (which after all the only bit which is used to actually dial the number), and then just format it in that particular way only when _displaying_ it)

Comment: Can you guarantee that the number as entered will be formatted with separators, and that the number will always have a country code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you. Jquery should be best way

```js
var USNumber = '+1 (213) 435-4676'; // I think this should be the format of mobile number

var zipcode = USNumber.split(" ")[1].replace("(", "").replace(")","");
alert(zipcode);

var Areacode = USNumber.split(" ")[2].split("-")[0];
alert(Areacode);

var Number = USNumber.split(" ")[2].split("-")[1];
alert(Number);
```